# Maven project architecture

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jakarta-ee

I am trying to add the locally created project which contains JARs added using java build path to my maven project as dependency and the JARs used in the dependency project are also be useful in the main project. how to deal in this scenario if I don't want to convert my dependency project to maven?

Comment: Deploy that jar to a repository manager and start to use one..This will solve the issue. Just use it as a usual dependency....

Answer (score 0):

You have different possibilities:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>...</groupId>
  <artifactId>...</artifactId>
  <version>2.53.1</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>
    C:/.../your-jar.jar
  </systemPath>
</dependency>
```

or you can install it in your local .m2 repo
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

This doesn't force you in any way to convert your project into a maven project, but let you reuse the jar you already have.

Comment: I have done this already but it is giving classnotfoundexception for the JARs which are there in dependency project

Comment: scope "system" is really not best solution, this scope is working similar with scope provided: e.g. the JAR(s) will not included in target WAR and so on.

Project Local Repository is the best way to do it. If you need example: https://github.com/Gmugra/net.cactusthorn.maven

Comment: Did you try to install it too?

Comment: @RohitHaval ok, but after installing it, how you tried to include in the project?
You should be able like a normal dependency.

Comment: Have done this already. using this approach, I am able to utilize the functionality of existing project but the JARs inside that project are not getting referred in the new project.

Comment: I think because those JARs are added using build path in the dependency project.

Comment: Ok. Maybe setting the scope of your dependency with "compile"? This should include it in the jar.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar like Maven multimodule project. In that all the submodules gets added to the root project as a jar after successful compile. In your case try covert the project into jar and copy the same jar file to the lib folder of parent project.